# std::vector<bool> guaranteed to default all entries to false?

Tags: c++, vector

I want all of the entries in my std::vector to be false after I resize it to the desired container size. This appears to be the case on testing, but I can't seem to find any documentation that guarantees this to always be the case.

I realize I could set everything to false myself, but this seems inefficient if it is already guaranteed to default to false for every entry (it is a decent sized vector and will be created in thousands of places).

Is there any guarantee of this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`resize` will default-insert elements, going by the (C++11) standard this calls:

`allocator_traits<bool>::construct(m, p)`

Where `m` is an allocator, and `p` points to the target address.

This in turn (assuming `m` is a standard allocator) calls

`m.construct(p)`

which in turn calls

`::new((void *)p) bool()`

So your `bool` ends up being value-initialized, which for `bool`s means zero-initialization, which means `false`.

If `m` is a custom allocator and for some reason is missing `construct()`, it still ends up being value-initialized.

---

As it has been pointed out `std::vector<bool>` does not use the standard allocator, still `resize()` is defined as

`void resize(size_type sz, bool c = false);`

so the result is the same.

Comment: Unlike other vectors, `vector<bool>` doesn't use `allocator_traits<bool>::construct`.

Comment: Good point...although it does go on to say that all operations have the same requirements so at least the result is the same. Or is it?

Comment: According to [cpprference's `vector<bool>` entry](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), "Does not use std::allocator_traits::construct to construct bit values.".  I wouldn't have downvoted you, but then there's no other way to undo my having upvoted you, and the answer is wrong...."

Comment: @TonyD Understandable, I've edited my answer now. For future reference i think you can click the same arrow to undo a +/-1.

Comment: @user657267: might be good to put the most relevant info at the top, and keep the "BTW for vectors of types other than bool..." stuff as a bonus section at the end.  +1 from me anyway, and thanks for the tip re voting... that's cool!  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a `std::vector<bool>` is initialized with zeroed bytes, which are `false` (the default value for initialized `bool`-s) on most machines.

See the note on [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Never noticed the "if not initialized with a custom allocator" to be honest, +1

Comment: `bool()`, the default value, is false on ALL c++ systems, not most.

Comment: @David: I think it's new to C++11, as C++03 only had the single version `resize(n, T default_value = T())`. `int()` is zero regardless of the allocator.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, if you use:

```
vec.resize(N, false);
```

Every entry should be set to `false`. Isn't that what you need ?

Moreover, if you don't specify `false`, it'll take the default value, which is `false` for `bool`.

Answer (score -4):

Not guaranteed. Better would be to have

```
struct MYBOOL {
    int value;
    MYBOOL(bool v = false):value(v) {}
    operator bool(){return value;}
};
```

And have your vector declared as:

```
vector<MYBOOL> v(10); // presume size = 10
```

When you access some element in vector, say v[2], it is guaranteed to be false unless you do something like below:

```
v[2] = true;
```

before accessing v[2]

or use v.push_back(true);

Comment: I guess not for primitive type bool. do you mean to say bool b; will guarantee that b as false? I doubt!

Comment: @DebasishJana The only doubt would arise because `std::vector<bool>` is a weird specialization, so some of the usual rules do not apply. But for any other built-in type, the elements are zero-initialized.

Comment: But I thought primitive types don't have constructor(s) to get initialized

Comment: @DebasishJana: Depends a **lot** on context. The exact rules won't fit in a comment but basically the syntax `T foo = T()` initializes `foo` regardless of the type `T`, even if `T` has no constructor. That's what happens here too: the default second argument of `vector<T>::resize` is `T()`.